# How can I make ubuntu14 desktop like win 7

Tags: xubuntu

I have Ubuntu 14 running in vmware but I want to make the desktop look like Windows 7. I tried

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

but when logged out I can't see xfce session.

I also tried

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/gtk3 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install win2-7 
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme 'Win2-7-theme' 
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'menu:minimize,maximize,close'
```

to no avail.

Comment: Possibly this link should help you! N`http://www.itworld.com/article/2699529/enterprise-software/install-windows-xp-theme-in-ubuntu-13-10.html`

Comment: Check out Cinnamon desktop. Its Start Menu is very similar to Windows'

Answer (score 0):

A better look at [this B00merang project](https://b00merang.weebly.com/windows-7.html). It has plenty of themes for all operating systems.